# Baidu web search engine API

Tags: c#, .net, api

The English version of baidu doesn't have meaningfull information about how to obtain or use their API. I've tried writing several emails, but no response so far.
Google translate tries to translate the Chinese version, but with no luck.
Has anyone yet found a way or someone to give more info about web/images search using Baudi API?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have just started to look at the Baidu API, and have similarly found that their documentation is all in Chinese, with extremely little available in English (or any other language). And I do not speak Chinese!

The biggest help I have found so far is the Java example code that can be found here : http://dev2.baidu.com/sms_zh/en/Java#page=Java#page=Java#page=Java

(There is a ZIP file you can download at the bottom of the page.)

That should give you an idea of how to use the API, even if it's not a substitute for real documentation.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: Apparently there is no web search option, or images search, like the one that Google offers, and Yahoo, Bing, Yandex, etc. 

This example is for campaign creations, with keywords, geo locationes, etc, thing which an advertiser should need to publish ads.

The weirdest thing is that all my emails sent to their dev and support email, were in English, their answer was in Chinese, although one person responded me in English with API specification for creating campaigns, which i don't need.

No answer since then. I guess the old fashion way with scraping should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.

Seems like baidu doesn't have an API to get search results. 
You can use SerpApi in order to get scraped results for organic search.
You can check [playgound](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=baidu&q=coffee) and [documentation](https://serpapi.com/baidu-search-api) to find out if this will cover your needs. There is also a .net client [library](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-dotnet).